# PhoneGap - Unable to install via npm, phonegap does not exist

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I am trying to download and run PhoneGap.  I have tried on 3 machines (2 mac, 1 windows), and I can't help but feel as though I am doing something wrong.

I have nodeJS (v0.10.13) and NPM (1.3.2) installed to the latest versions, using homebrew.

To install PhoneGap I do the following via commandline:
`sudo npm install -g phonegap`

NPM goes on it's merry way downloading a ton of packages and installing all without warning or error.

After install I get the following, which I assume is correct:

```
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1/-/asn1-0.1.11.tgz
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/phonegap -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/phonegap/bin/phonegap.js
phonegap@3.0.0-0.14.0 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/phonegap
├── pluralize@0.0.4
├── colors@0.6.0-1
├── semver@1.1.0
├── qrcode-terminal@0.9.4
├── shelljs@0.1.4
├── optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.1)
├── node-static@0.7.0 (colors@0.6.0, mime@1.2.9)
├── phonegap-build@0.8.3 (qrcode-terminal@0.8.0, optimist@0.3.7, shelljs@0.0.9, phonegap-build-api@0.3.3)
├── prompt@0.2.11 (revalidator@0.1.5, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.5, winston@0.6.2, utile@0.2.0)
└── cordova@3.0.0 (ncallbacks@1.0.0, colors@0.6.0, open@0.0.3, shelljs@0.1.2, follow-redirects@0.0.3, elementtree@0.1.3, glob@3.2.3, plist@0.4.3, prompt@0.2.7, xcode@0.5.1, tar@0.1.17, express@3.0.0, ripple-emulator@0.9.18, plugman@0.9.10, request@2.22.0)
MikeBook-Pro:apps Mike$
```

I then restart terminal (completely quit it, cmd+q) and run `phonegap`, to be greeted with:

```
MikeBook-Pro:~ Mike$ phonegap
-bash: phonegap: command not found
```

I'm at my wits end here.  I've installed other stuff through NPM without a problem.  My `/etc/paths` looks like the following:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

I have followed the above steps using `cordova` instead of `phonegap`, but alas; the same issue.

Any help is hugely appreciated, I just want to cry.

Edit: I'm currently trying this on OSX 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was some how missing a few paths from my `/etc/paths` file.  Below is that new file:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin

/usr/local/share
/usr/local/share/npm
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/
/usr/local/share/npm/bin
.npm
```